# MySQL update not updating all records

Tags: mysql, transactions, commit

I have a database table that lists all orders. Each weekend a cron runs and it generates invoices for each customer. The code loops through each customer, gets their recent orders, creates a PDF and then updates the orders table to record the invoice ID against each of their orders.

The final update query is:

update bookings set invoiced='12345' where username='test-username' and invoiced='';

So, set invoiced to 12345 for all orders for test-username that haven't been previously invoiced.

I have come across a problem where orders are being added to the PDF but not updated to reflect the fact that they have been invoiced.

I have started running the update query manually and come across a strange scenario.

A customer may have 60 orders.

If I run the query once then 1 order is updated. I run it again and 1 order is updated, I repeat the process and each time only a small number of orders are updated - between 1 and 3. It doesn't update the 60 in one query as I would expect. I need to run the query repeatedly until it finally comes back with "0 rows affected" and then I can be sure that all rows have been updated.

I am not including a LIMIT XX in my query so I so no reason why it can't update all orders at once. The query I run repeatedly is identical each time.

Does anybody have any wise suggestions?!

Comment: Can you add a `SELECT` query here, to check what records should be affected (like `SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE username = :username AND invoiced = ''`) - and log its results?

Comment: Hi - yes, this is the strange thing. If I do a SELECT for the exact same query then I see the full results - e.g. 60 rows. If I then run an update then it only does 1 or 2.

Comment: Ok, I assume here the same query runs ok when done in plain MySQL (via console, for example)... Can you show the code itself then?

Comment: Hi. Yes, I have been doing it via phpMyAdmin to confirm the SELECT and UPDATE are doing what I have said.

Comment: Well, like I said, the code that does the thing is interesting here.

Comment: What code though? It's the SQL query that's producing strange results and that's what I have given above.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something, but could you explain how exactly you execute this SQL query in the cron job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using InnoDB. You haven't disclosed the type of code you're running.

But I bet you're seeing an issue that relates to transactions. When a program works differently from an interactive session, it's often a transaction issue.

See here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html

Do things work better if you issue a `COMMIT;` command right after your `UPDATE` statement?

Note that your language binding may have its own preferred way of issuing the `COMMIT;` command.

Another way to handle this problem is to issue the SQL command

```
 SET autocommit = 1
```

right after you establish your connection. This will make every SQL command that changes data do its COMMIT operation automatically.